# Convert Ascii value directly to Hex value

Tags: java, hex

I have a literal String made of the hexadecimal alphabet such as `00bff040dadd1fde55` and I wish to convert the string into its hex 'equivalent' in bytes i.e. into a byte array such as `{0x00 0xBF 0xF0 0x40 0xDA 0xDD 0x1F 0xDE 0x55}`

Is there a Java class that can do this conversion? If not, does anyone have an algorithm I can implement to do the above conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want to separate the string into bytes of hex, you can use a regular expression:

```
String s = "00bff040dadd1fde55";
String hex = "{" + s.toUpperCase().replaceAll("(..)", "0x$1 ").trim() + "}";
System.out.println(hex);
```

Prints:

```
{0x00 0xBF 0xF0 0x40 0xDA 0xDD 0x1F 0xDE 0x55}
```

If you mean you want a byte array to result:

```
int size = s.length() / 2;
byte[] arr = new byte[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    arr[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 2), 16);
}
```

To prove the array contains the right bytes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(String.format("%02X ", arr[i]) + " ");
}
```

Prints:

```
00  BF  F0  40  DA  DD  1F  DE  55
```

Comment: While this is correct, and I think the question was rather confusing, I think it asked for a conversion into a byte array, not a string of neatly formatted byte values.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't sure. I've added two different endings. Hopefully one of them will be happy.

Comment: @aetheria yes, a byte array is what I wanted. I have edited the question to make that clear. Thanks for the sample code!

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a Java class that can do this conversion?

There is no class in the standard library that will convert a string containing hex characters into an array of bytes ... like that<sup>1</sup>.

> If not, does anyone have an algorithm I can implement to do the above conversion?

1. Divide length of the string by 2, and allocate byte array of that size.
2. Repeat until string is empty:

   1. Remove a substring comprising the first two characters.
   2. Use `Integer.parseInt(twoChars, 16)` to convert to an integer.
   3. Cast the integer to byte and add to byte array.

This algorithm can easily be converted to Java code.

---

<sup>1 - If you actually want a sequence of byte "literals" represented as a string, then look at @aetheria's answer ...</sup>